# How should I go about installing Chrome on ubuntu 14.04 32bit?

Tags: google-chrome, 32-bit

I would like to install Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, but it's no longer
supported.

Comment: So use Chromium?

Comment: You don't. Use another browser.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question.

Answer (score 11):

You can install it, but it's not advisable. Chrome 32-bit is no longer receiving security updates (or updates of any kind, for that matter). That means you won't get new features, extensions will soon stop working, and you will be extremely vulnerable to internet attacks.

The best thing to do in your case is really to upgrade to a 64-bit version of Ubuntu. However, I realize this may not be possible, as your computer may be limited to 32-bit. If that is the case, there is an alternative to Chrome, called Chromium.

Chromium is essentially Chrome, but it is open-source, and doesn't quite receive the level of support Chrome gets. However, it is regularly updated and receives any security updates released by Google. Many other browsers, such as Torch, and even Opera, are based on Chromium.

If you want to install Chromium, simply open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. You can also open the Software Center and search for it if you so wish.

There is absolutely no reason to keep with Chrome on 32-bit or 12.04, but if you really want to install it for whatever reason, you'll have to search for it on Google. A quick search yielded nothing but news stories for me.

Comment: Cheers for the package name - 'chromium' wasn't working but I suppose that's just me used to the debian convention

Answer (score 6):

from other search got this link:
http://bbgentoo.ilb.ru/distfiles/  look for google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: To be fair, the question isn't even a question. :) This is a good answer to the implied question "how do I get a 32-bit version of Chrome installed on a 32-bit ubuntu if I really must have Chrome, not chromium, and I understand the implications of using unsupported and no longer security patched software".

Comment: Has anyone try the package? Is the package safe?

Answer (score 3):

There is alternate web browser you can choose to install that is Chromium.

Go to Ubuntu Software Center and Then click on Internet Category.

From there click Web browser to install Chromium.